# how to change android Progress Dialog message typeface?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Who can answer my bellow question ?

how to change android Progress Dialog message typeface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way , worked for me :

First in java class  you have to import this :

```
 import android.text.Html;
```

then put this line :

```
progressDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.progress_txt)));
```

instead of this:

```
    progressDialog.setMessage("File downloading");
```

then in strings.xml write it as this :

```
 <string name="progress_txt">
  <![CDATA[
  <b><font face="serif">File downloading</font></b>
    ]]> 
 </string>
```

run the app you will find  typeface already changed .

Hope this help

Comment: I did not edited the progress dialog content view, i wanna use the default dialog

Comment: But this solution is useless for a custom font in the assets folder. Totally, it's not possible to change typeface in a XML file.

Comment: @AndroidStack can you please tell me how to change it from .ttf file in assets folder?