# Is there a simple way to change background and font color of ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android

I need to change the background color of the ProgressDialog to black and the color of the fonts to white. Is there a simple way of doing it with code? (It must be compatible with Android 2.3+)

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog

Answer (score 0):

Yes, read following articles :

[Change background of ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog)

[how to change android Progress Dialog message typeface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271646/how-to-change-android-progress-dialog-message-typeface)

Always search for similar titles before asking ;)